# dispatch_async equivalent in xamarin.ios?

Tags: multithreading, xamarin, xamarin.ios

What is the equivalent of the following code in Xamarin.iOS?

```
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^(void){
        //Background Thread
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
            //Run UI Updates
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here's pretty much the C# equivalent of your code:

```
using CoreFoundation;

DispatchQueue.GetGlobalQueue(DispatchQueuePriority.Default).DispatchAsync(() =>
{
    DispatchQueue.MainQueue.DispatchAsync(() => { });
});
```